# Annual Percent Change in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate an annual percentage change in Power BI using DAX and need help here.
This is my data source in Power BI:
[image]

Then I calculated an average rent using this formula (for "studio" type):

```
AVGRentStudio = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Rental Trend'[Rent]),'Rental Trend'[Type] = "Studio")
```

And I got a tabular presentation of average values:
[image]

Now I would like to calculate an annual percentage change (to the previous year).

This is what I tried, but the result isn't accurate.

```
RentChange =
CALCULATE (
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Rental Trend'[Year] ),
        DIVIDE (
            SUM ( 'Rental Trend'[Rent] ),
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( 'Rental Trend'[Rent] ),
                'Rental Trend'[Year]
                    = FORMAT ( VALUES ( 'Rental Trend'[Year] ) - 1, BLANK () )
            )
        )
    )
        - 1,
    'Rental Trend'[Type] = "Studio"
```

Can anyone help how to calculate the annual percentage change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rado I got an idea based on your answer.

Measure 1 (for previous year):

```
AVG Rent Studio PY = CALCULATE(IF(HASONEVALUE('Rental Trend'[Year]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Rental Trend'[Rent]), 'Rental Trend'[Year] = FORMAT(VALUES('Rental Trend'[Year]) - 1, BLANK()), 'Rental Trend'[Type] = "Studio")))
```

Measure 2 (selected year):

```
VG Rent Studio CY = IF(HASONEVALUE('Rental Trend'[Year]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Rental Trend'[Rent]), 'Rental Trend'[Type] = "Studio"))
```

Measure 3 (year-to-year change):

```
Y/Y Rent Change = 1 - DIVIDE([AVG Rent Studio PY],[AVG Rent Studio CY])
```

Can I make this solution dynamic in order to show year-to-year change based on "Type" selection - Studio, 1BDR, 2BDR?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

Measure 1:

```
Average Rent Studio =
CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( 'Rental Trend'[Rent] ), 'Rental Trend'[Type] = "Studio" )
```

Measure 2:

```
Average Rent Studio Previous Year =
VAR Current_Year = MAX ( 'Rental Trend'[Year] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( [Average Rent Studio], 'Rental Trend'[Year] = Current_Year - 1 )
```

Measure 3:

```
Average Rent Studio Y/Y Change = 
DIVIDE([Average Rent Studio], [Average Rent Studio Previous Year])
```

How it works:
Measures 1 and 3 are simple. 
in Measure 2, you first need to capture current year (it's the max year in a given filter context) and store it in a variable. Then recalculate studio rent using 1 year before the saved year.